# how to compute the sum for each pair of rows x in matrice X and y in matrice Y?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a function in python that takes as input two matrices X and Y and computes for every pair of rows x in X and y in  Y, the norm ||x - y|| . I would like to do it without using for loops.
Do you have an idea about how to do it ?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you showed what you are starting with, the output you want, and what you've tried.

Comment: in fact i am trying to write a gaussian RBF kernel function. Given 2 matrices X and Y the gaussian RBF kernel is : K(x, y) = exp(-gamma ||x-y||^2) for each pair of rows x in X and y in Y.                                                                                                                         X is a (n, d) numpy array and Y a (m, d) numpy array.                                                    I want to return a (n, m) numpy array containing the kernel matrix

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a for loop by using the function `numpy.linalg.norm`

```
x = np.array([[5, 4, 1],
              [3, 2, 1]])
y = np.array([[5, 4, 2],
              [3, 3, 2]])
np.linalg.norm(x - y, axis=1)
```

`>> array([1.        , 1.41421356])`

To do the same but column-wise, use `axis=0`

`np.linalg.norm(x - y, axis=0)`

`>>array([0.        , 1.        , 1.41421356])`

Answer (score 0):

I just solve it :D
instead of len(np.trnspose(y)) i had to do len(y) and it perfectly worked with a for loop.